# How can I make a deepcopy of a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, copy, deep-copy

I would like to make a deepcopy of a function in Python.  The *copy* module is not helpful, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html), which says:

> This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, 
>   socket, window, array, or any similar types. It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow 
>   and deeply), by returning the original object unchanged; this is compatible with the way
>   these are treated by the pickle module.

My goal is to have two functions with the same implementation but with different docstrings.

```
def A():
    """A"""
    pass

B = make_a_deepcopy_of(A)
B.__doc__ = """B"""
```

So how can this be done?

Comment: Do you want them to have the same `__name__`?

Comment: Eh, I'm not too concerned about that, as I could easily change it once I have a copy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The FunctionType constructor is used to make a deep copy of a function.

```
import types
def copy_func(f, name=None):
    return types.FunctionType(f.func_code, f.func_globals, name or f.func_name,
        f.func_defaults, f.func_closure)

def A():
    """A"""
    pass
B = copy_func(A, "B")
B.__doc__ = """B"""
```

Comment: @GlennMaynard : this can’t work for built‑in functions http://stackoverflow.com/q/39353158/2284570

Comment: Only works in python 2. See [Aaron Hall's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714299/425458) post below for an answer that's py 2/3 compatible.

Answer (score 30):

> ### My goal is to have two functions with the same implementation but with different docstrings.

Most users will do this, say the original function is in `old_module.py`:

```
def implementation(arg1, arg2): 
    """this is a killer function"""
```

and in `new_module.py`

```
from old_module import implementation as _implementation

def implementation(arg1, arg2):
    """a different docstring"""
    return _implementation(arg1, arg2)
```

This is the most straightforward way to reuse functionality. It is easy to read and understand the intent.

Nevertheless, perhaps you have a good reason for your main question:

> ### How can I make a deepcopy of a function in Python?

To keep this compatible with Python 2 *and* 3, I recommend using the function's special `__dunder__` attributes. For example:

```
import types

def copy_func(f, name=None):
    '''
    return a function with same code, globals, defaults, closure, and 
    name (or provide a new name)
    '''
    fn = types.FunctionType(f.__code__, f.__globals__, name or f.__name__,
        f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
    # in case f was given attrs (note this dict is a shallow copy):
    fn.__dict__.update(f.__dict__) 
    return fn
```

And here's an example usage:

```
def main():
    from logging import getLogger as _getLogger # pyflakes:ignore, must copy
    getLogger = copy_func(_getLogger)
    getLogger.__doc__ += '\n    This function is from the Std Lib logging module.\n    '
    assert getLogger.__doc__ is not _getLogger.__doc__
    assert getLogger.__doc__ != _getLogger.__doc__
```

A commenter says:

> This can’t work for built‑in functions

Well I wouldn't *do* this for a built-in function. I have very little reason to do this for functions written in pure Python, and my suspicion is that if you are doing this, you're probably doing something very wrong (though I could be wrong here).

If you want a function that does what a builtin function does, and reuses the implementation, like a copy would, then you should wrap the function with another function, e.g.:

```
_sum = sum
def sum(iterable, start=0):
    """sum function that works like the regular sum function, but noisy"""
    print('calling the sum function')
    return _sum(iterable, start)
```

Comment: This can’t work for built‑in functions http://stackoverflow.com/q/39353158/2284570

Comment: py 2/3 compatibility for the win!

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503277/10155767) of a duplicate problem is very similar, but also takes into account a few further subtleties such as `__kwdefaults__`.

Comment: Maybe this technique isn't well motivated for docstrings, but I'm glad you wrote the tutorial because I really needed it! I needed a copy of a suite of functions, which call each other, to be copied to a new (dynamic) module and call each others' copies, rather than the originals. This meant replacing their `__globals__` to point to the new module. The reason for all of this was to Numba-compile all of the copied functions without affecting the original functions, since they still need to be accessed in pure object mode. So thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
from functools import partial

def a():
    """Returns 1"""
    return 1

b = partial(a)
b.__doc__ = """Returns 1, OR DOES IT!"""

print help(a)
print help(b)
```

Wrap it as a partial?

Comment: So the only reason I think this is not as "nice" is that from an IPython terminal, one cannot look at the source of b, via "b??".  Strictly a personal preference.

Comment: God damn it! try the bpython console

Comment: @JakobBowyer : using this solution you don’t get a copy of `a`, but you wrap `a` in a `functools.partial object`.

Comment: `b = lambda *args, **kwargs: a(*args, **kwargs)` works as well, but a bit more verbose

Answer (score 2):

```
def A():
    """A"""
    pass

def B():
    """B"""
    return A()
```

Comment: It works, but is there something nicer...which doesn't increase the function call overhead? I literally just want a copy.

Comment: I guess, even if there would be a way, it won't be 'nicer'

Comment: I agree it won't be nicer, but since I am calling this function in for loops nested a few levels down, I went with the factory method.

Answer (score 2):

The others answers do not allow for serialization with pickle. Here a code that I am using to clone a function and allow for serialization for python3:

```py
import pickle
import dill
import types

def foo():
    print ('a')


oldCode=foo.__code__

name='IAmFooCopied'

newCode= types.CodeType(
        oldCode.co_argcount,             #   integer
        oldCode.co_kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
        oldCode.co_nlocals,              #   integer
        oldCode.co_stacksize,            #   integer
        oldCode.co_flags,                #   integer
        oldCode.co_code,                 #   bytes
        oldCode.co_consts,               #   tuple
        oldCode.co_names,                #   tuple
        oldCode.co_varnames,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_filename,             #   string
        name,                  #   string
        oldCode.co_firstlineno,          #   integer
        oldCode.co_lnotab,               #   bytes
        oldCode.co_freevars,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_cellvars              #   tuple
        )

IAmFooCopied=types.FunctionType(newCode, foo.__globals__, name,foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__)
IAmFooCopied.__qualname__= name
print ( 'printing foo and the copy', IAmFooCopied, foo )
print ( 'dill output: ', dill.dumps(IAmFooCopied ))
print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (IAmFooCopied) )
```

Output:

```
printing foo and the copy <function IAmFooCopied at 0x7f8a6a8159d8> <function foo at 0x7f8a6b5f5268>
dill output:  b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x0ct\x00d\x01\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x00S\x00q\x05NX\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x06\x86q\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00printq\x08\x85q\t)X\x10\x00\x00\x00testCloneFunc.pyq\nX\x0c\x00\x00\x00IAmFooCopiedq\x0bK\x05C\x02\x00\x01q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x0ftq\x10Rq\x11.'
pickle Output:  b'\x80\x03c__main__\nIAmFooCopied\nq\x00.'
```

You may encounter problem with the **qualname** attribute if you try this snippet with class methods (I think pickle should fail to find your function). I never tried it, however it should be easily fixable. Just check the doc about **qualname**

Comment: somehow people overlooked this piece

Comment: **Brilliant.** This is undeniably the optimally efficient solution to function copying both here [and elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503079/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-python-function). Sadly, it lacks upvotes. Sadly, it's also incomplete. Why? Because it fails to copy the `__kwdefaults__`, `__module__`, `__qualname__`, `__doc__`, and `__annotations__` attributes from the old to new function. Fortunately, *all* of those attributes can be trivially copied by just calling `functools.update_wrapper(IAmFooCopied, foo, functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('__kwdefaults__',))`. **Yup.**

Comment: **Addendum:** [the new `CodeType.replace()` method introduced in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType.replace) is strongly preferable to reconstructing a new `CodeType` object from scratch. Why? Because future-proofing. The `CodeType` constructor frequently changes between Python versions, which then breaks everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do using `lambda` and rest parameters:

```py
def my_copy(f): 
        # Create a lambda that mimics f
        g = lambda *args: f(*args)
        # Add any properties of f
        t = list(filter(lambda prop: not ("__" in prop),dir(f)))
        i = 0
        while i < len(t):
            setattr(g,t[i],getattr(f,t[i]))
            i += 1
        return g
        
# Test
def sqr(x): return x*x
sqr.foo = 500

sqr_copy = my_copy(sqr)
print(sqr_copy(5)) # -> 25
print(sqr_copy(6)) # -> 36
print(sqr_copy.foo) # -> 500
print(sqr_copy == sqr) # -> False
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBT4QwEIXv/RWT3Uu7iwbdsAciJsbEX@DNGFKXFppAi@0Y4ddjiwVxe@p73@TN5PUjNkafpqkSErqxvJh@pJLlQCC@PTxbwVEAh5Z3HxUHbDhCpzp1cSDXuRqKZeDAbe1ykHT@sE3UU1UB1yP01vTCohIOjNyEYAhRDqlULQpLY2AYz0EbBLoryx0oPVssqZT117K/FcoHpKv6blQrvPcArdAUWb6S8JxAjmhpneCbek/qKOUsN5m/uccC7lbLCvyyGurVIHt4FQ5JqNF9Wjr4CuPQcBiIt26lMf64LE1JkHPTXi@de4uR3iqNdKE0Y8x3dvMI99k1Oi/odL5CYU9kYdd/CEURzov8hbdOTNMP)

Answer (score 0):

put it in a function:

```
def makefunc( docstring ):
    def f():
        pass
    f.__doc__ = docstring
    return f

f = makefunc('I am f')
g = makefunc("I am f too")
```

Comment: Alright, I guess I am going to cave in and accept this. I was hoping there was something which didn't rely or wrapping or a construction, but I suppose it ultimately comes down to that at some level.

Comment: @Tom did you not look at my example? It shows basically the syntax you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted for python3

```
import types
def copy_func(f, name=None):
    return types.FunctionType(f.__code__, f.__globals__, name or f.__name__,
        f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
def func1(x):
  return 2*x
func2=copy_func(func1)
print(func2(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a general-purpose function copy in [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), a library which I wrote and maintain (available with `pip` but probably not `conda`). [`haggis.objects.copy_func`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.objects.copy_func) makes a copy on which you can not only reassign the `__doc__` attribute, but also modify the module and `__globals__` attributes effectively.

```
from haggis.objects import copy_func

def a(*args, **kwargs):
    """A docstring"""

a2 = copy_func(a)
a2.__doc__ = """Another docstring"""
```

```
>>> a == a2
False
>>> a.__code__ == a2.__code__
True
>>> a.__doc__
'A docstring'
>>> a2.__doc__
'Another docstring'
```