# How to create an independent copy of a function in python?

Tags: python, function, lambda, copy, deep-copy

Is it possible in python to create an un-linked copy of a function? For example, if I have

```
a = lambda(x): x
b = lambda(x): a(x)+1
```

I want `b(x)` to always `return x+1`, regardless if `a(x)` is modified not. Currently, if I do

```
a = lambda(x): x
b = lambda(x): a(x)+1
print a(1.),b(1.)
a = lambda(x): x*0
print a(1.),b(1.)
```

the output is

```
1. 2.
0. 1.
```

Instead of being

```
1. 2.
0. 2.
```

as I would like to. Any idea on how to implement this? It seems that using `deepcopy` does not help for functions. Also keep in mind that `a(x)` is created externally and I can't change its definition. I've also looked into using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503079/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-python-function), but it did not help.

Comment: This is a very unusual question.  How is the `a` function changing?  What changes it?

Comment: If you're worried about someone reassigning `a`, what if they just reassign `b`?

Comment: The main reason why a is changing is because it is located in a loop. For example:

lambdas1 = [lambda(x): return x,lambda(x): return x*x]
b = []
for i range(2):
  a = lambdas[i]
  b.append(lambda(x): a(x)+1)

The problem is that each element of b is bounded to the definition of a. When i==1, the definition of a is changed, so is the definition of b[0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define b like this:

```
b = lambda x, a=a: a(x)+1
```

This makes `a` a parameter of `b`, and therefore a local variable.  You default it to the value of `a` in the current environment, so `b` will hold onto that value.  You don't need to copy `a`, just keep its current value, so that if a new value is created, you have the one you wanted.

That said, this sounds like something unusual happening, and if you tell us more about what's going on, there's likely a better answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! In the mean time, I also found a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I might need to know a little more about your constraints before I can give a satisfactory answer. Why couldn't you do something like

```
a = lambda(x): x
c = a
b = lambda(x): c(x)+1
```

Then no matter what happens to `a`, `b` will stay the same. This works because of the somewhat unusual way that assignment works in Python. When you do `c = a`, the name `c` is linked to the object that `a` links to. You can use `id()` to look at that object's id and see that they are the same; `c` and `a` point to the same object.

```
c = a
id(a)
>>> 4410483968
id(c)
>>> 4410483968
```

Then, when you redefine `a` with `a = lambda x: x*0`, you're actually doing two things in one line. First, `lambda x: x*0` creates a new function object, then the assignment causes the name `a` to be linked to the new object. As you can see, `a` is now pointing to a different object:

```
a = lambda x: x*0
id(a)
>>>> 4717817680
```

But if you look at `id(c)`, it still points to the old object!

```
id(c)
>>>> 4410483968
```

This is because when we redefined `a`, we merely created a new object and linked `a` to it. `c` remains linked to the old one.

So if you redefine `a` as you do in the question, you get the output you want:

```
print a(1.),b(1.)
>>>> 0.0,2.0
```

Comment: Would be an even better answer IMHO if you explained _why_ or how it worked.

Comment: The problem remains the same. If c is changed somehow later in the execution, you definition of b will also change.

It is problematic where you are trying to define b in a loop, while a (or c) is also part of that loop. @NedBatchelder provided a more suitable answer below.