# Override globals in function imported from another module

Tags: python, global-variables

Let's say I have two modules:

**a.py**

```
value = 3
def x()
    return value
```

**b.py**

```
from a import x
value = 4
```

My goal is to use the functionality of `a.x` in `b`, but change the value returned by the function. Specifically, `value` will be looked up with `a` as the source of global names even when I run `b.x()`. I am basically trying to create a copy of the function object in `b.x` that is identical to `a.x` but uses `b` to get its globals. Is there a reasonably straightforward way to do that?

Here is an example:

```
import a, b

print(a.x(), b.x())
```

The result is currently `3 3`, but I want it to be `3 4`.

I have come up with two convoluted methods that work, but I am not happy with either one:

1. Re-define `x` in module `b` using copy-and paste. The real function is much more complex than shown, so this doesn't sit right with me.
2. Define a parameter that can be passed in to x and just use the module's value:

   ```
   def x(value):
       return value
   ```

   This adds a burden on the user that I want to avoid, and does not really solve the problem.

Is there a way to modify where the function gets its globals somehow?

Comment: You want something like return reference in C++ ?

Comment: @liliscent Not sure what that is, but I added an example of exactly what I want.

Comment: If you only want to modify a variable in another module, just use `a.value` to access it. I don't know why you mention that function `x()`.

Comment: Because I want to make a copy of the function object in `b` that refers to `b`'s globals instead of `a`'s.

Comment: @liliscent. Perhaps it is more clear now?

Comment: I think you need a class instead of global variable. Essentially you want 2 identical function operating on different `value`. This `value` should be a class member.

Comment: @liliscent. I can do it for a class. However, I have a case where I can not avoid using globals as shown, but I would like to replace the source of them. An explanation of why that is not possible would answer my question as well. I suspect, however, that since this is Python, there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come up with a solution through a mixture of guess-and-check and research. You can do pretty much exactly what I proposed in the question: [copy a function object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13503079/2988730) and replace its `__globals__` attribute.

I am using Python 3, so here is a modified version of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503277/2988730) to the question linked above, with an added option to override the globals:

```
import copy
import types
import functools

def copy_func(f, globals=None, module=None):
    """Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503277/2988730 (@unutbu)"""
    if globals is None:
        globals = f.__globals__
    g = types.FunctionType(f.__code__, globals, name=f.__name__,
                           argdefs=f.__defaults__, closure=f.__closure__)
    g = functools.update_wrapper(g, f)
    if module is not None:
        g.__module__ = module
    g.__kwdefaults__ = copy.copy(f.__kwdefaults__)
    return g
```

**b.py**

```
from a import x
value = 4
x = copy_func(x, globals(), __name__)
```

The `__globals__` attribute is read-only, which is why it must be passed to the constructor of `FunctionType`. The `__globals__` reference of an existing function object can not be changed.

**Postscript**

I've used this enough times now that it's implemented in a utility library I wrote and maintain called `haggis`. See [`haggis.objects.copy_func`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.objects.copy_func).

Comment: @chrisz. I've added an option to even fake the module that the function is defined in

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to (sort of) do this, although I don't think it entirely solves your problems.  Using inspect, you can access the global variables of the file calling your function.  So if you set up your files like so:

**a.py**

```
import inspect

value = 3

def a():
    return inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals['value']
```

**b.py**

```
from a import a

value = 5

print(a())
```

The output is 5, instead of 3.  However, if you imported both of these into a third file, it would look for the globals of the third file.  Just wanted to share this snippet however.

Comment: I found something much more straightorward, but def +1 for this.

Comment: Mind sharing what you came up with? I have run into similar issues before and would be interested in your approach.

Comment: I've added an answer. It's a bit longer than what you have, but it is more correct for the purpose I have in mind. Perhaps it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But then I remembered `eval` was a thing.
Here's a much shorter version(if you don't need arguments):
**b.py:**

```
from a import x as xx

# Define globals for the function here
glob = {'value': 4}
def x():
    return eval(xx.__code__, glob)
```

Hopefully after 2 years it'll still be helpful

Comment: This assumes a much more specific interface than what I had in mind, but it certainly works in some cases. Also, this is better use of `eval` than usual.