# globals()['variable']=value set in a .py file does not reflect value changes when used in other .py file

Tags: python

**globalEx1.py**:

```
globals()['a']='100'

def setvalue(val):
    globals()['a'] = val
```

**globalEx2.py**:

```
from globalEx1 import *

print a
setvalue('200')
print a
```

On executing `globalEx2.py`:

Output:

```
100
100
```

How can I change value of `globals['a']` using a function, so that it reflects across the .py files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each module has its own globals. Python is behaving exactly as expected. Updating `globalEx1`'s `a` to point to something else isn't going to affect where `globalEx2`'s `a` is pointing.

There are various ways around this, depending on exactly what you want.

1. re-import `a` after the `setvalue()` call
2. `return a` and assign it, like `a = setvalue()`.
3. `import globalEx1` and use `globalEx1.a` instead of `a`. (Or use `import globalEx1 as` and a shorter name.)
4. pass `globalEx2`'s `globals()` as an argument to `setvalue` and set the value on that instead.
5. make `a` a mutable object *containing* your value, like a list, dict or `types.SimpleNamespace`, and mutate it in `setvalue`.
6. use `inspect` inside `setvalue` to get the caller's globals from its stack frame. (Convenient, but brittle.)

   ---

> Last option looks suitable for me.. it will do the job with minimal code change but can I update globals of multiple modules using same way? or it only gives me the caller's globals?

Option 6 is actually the riskiest. The caller itself basically becomes a hidden parameter to the function, so something like a decorator from another module can break it without warning. Option 4 just makes that hidden parameter explicit, so it's not so brittle.

If you need this to work across more than two modules, option 6 isn't good enough, since it only gives you the current call stack. Option 3 is probably the most reliable for what you seem to be trying to do.

---

> How does option 1 work? I mean is it about running again -> "from globalEx1 import *" because I have many variables like 'a'.

A module becomes an object when imported the first time and it's saved in the `sys.modules` cache, so importing it again doesn't execute the module again. A `from ... import` (even with the `*`) just gets attributes from that module object and adds them to the local scope (which is the module globals if done at the top level, that is, outside of any definition.)

The module object's `__dict__` is basically its globals, so any function that alters the module's globals will affect the resulting module object's attrs, even if it's done after the module was imported.

> We cannot do from 'globalEx1 import *' from a python function, any alternative to this?

The star syntax is only allowed at the top level. But remember that it's just reading attributes from the module object. So you can get a dict of all the module attributes like

```
return vars(globalEx1)
```

This will give you more than `*` would. It doesn't return names that begin with an `_` by default, or the subset specified in `__all__` otherwise. You can filter the resulting dict with a dict comprehension, and even `.update()` the globals dict for some other module with the result.

But rather than re-implementing this filtering logic, you could just use exec to make it the top level. Then the only weird key you'd get is `__builtins__`

```
namespace = {}
exec('from globalEx1 import *', namespace)
del namespace['__builtins__']
return namespace
```

Then you can `globals().update(namespace)` or whatever.

Using `exec` like this is probably considered bad form, but then so is `import *` to begin with, honestly.

Comment: let me try your work arounds, thanks for the quick response

Comment: Last option looks suitable for me.. it will do the job with minimal code change but can I update globals of multiple modules using same way? or it only gives me the caller's globals?

Comment: How does option 1 work? I mean is it about running again -> "from globalEx1 import *" because I have many variables like 'a'.

Comment: Perfect, exporting globalEx1 again worked for me.. and I will try to apply it for 'n' number of files!

Comment: We cannot do from 'globalEx1 import *' from a python function, any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, related to the fact that strings are immutable. The line `from globalEx1 import *` creates two references in the `globalEx2` module: `a` and `setvalue`. `globalEx2.a` initially refers to the same string object as `globalEx1.a`, since that's how imports work.

However, once you call `setvalue`, which operates on the globals of `globalEx1`, the value referenced by  `globalEx1.a` is replaced by another string object. Since strings are immutable, there is no way to do this in place. The value of  `globalEx2.a` remains bound to the original string object, as it should.

You have a couple of workarounds available here. The most pythonic is to fix the import in  `globalEx2`:

```
import globalEx1

print globalEx1.a
globalEx1.setvalue('200')
print globalEx1.a
```

Another option would be to use a mutable container for `a`, and access that:

```
globals()['a']=['100']

def setvalue(val):
    globals()['a'][0] = val
```

```
from globalEx1 import *

print a[0]
setvalue('200')
print a[0]
```

A third, and wilder option, is to make `globalEx2`'s `setvalue` a copy of the original function, but with its `__globals__` attribute set to the namespace of `globalEx2` instead of `globalEx1`:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
from types import FunctionType
from globalEx1 import *

_setvalue = FunctionType(setvalue.__code__, globals(), name=setvalue.__name__,
                           argdefs=setvalue.__defaults__,
                           closure=setvalue.__closure__)
_setvalue = functools.update_wrapper(_setvalue, setvalue)
_setvalue.__kwdefaults__ = f.__kwdefaults__
setvalue = _setvalue
del _setvalue

print a
...
```

The reason you have to make the copy is that `__globals__` is a read-only attribute, and also you don't want to mess with the function in `globalEx1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503277/2988730.

Comment: Thanks for the response, reading both the answers I understand that it is expected behavior. My scenario: "I have lot of .py files which are importing a single .py file where the globals() are defined and set, this was going good for years, until they wanted to a feature do dynamically change these global values which are used at multiple places in many .py files. So thought of adding a function which can set them globally without modifying any other .py

Comment: @Waman. Really your best option is fixing the imports, but I can understand why that may not be an option.

Comment: yeah, since it is a legacy code plus not written by me. I am in fact completely aware of all the references to globals of that single .py file. If re-importing could work as mentioned in one of the answers, then I could actually trigger a single method which in turn triggers the re-importing in other modules..

Answer (score 0):

Globals are imported only once at the beginning with the import statement. Thus, if the global is an immutable object like str, int, etc, any update will not be reflected. However, if the global is a mutable object like list, etc, updates will be reflected. For example,

globalEx1.py:

```
globals()['a']=[100]

def setvalue(val):
    globals()['a'][0] = val
```

The output will be changed as expected:

```
[100]
[200]
```

### Aside

It's easier to define globals like normal variables:

```
a = [100]

def setvalue(value):
    a[0] = value
```

Or when editing value of immutable objects:

```
a = 100

def setvalue(value):
    global a
    a = value
```