# Pickle error while cloning a function : Can't pickle it's not the same object as

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, python-internals, dill

I encounter a really strange problem while trying to clone a function in python, using [How to create a copy of a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503079/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-python-function) technique

A minimal code that show the issue :

```py
import dill
import pickle
import types

def foo():
    print ('a')

fooCopy=types.FunctionType(foo.__code__, foo.__globals__, 'IAmFooCopied',foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__)

print ( 'printing foo and the copy', fooCopy, foo )
print ( 'dill output: ', dill.dumps(fooCopy ))
print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (fooCopy) )
```

Output:

```
printing foo and the copy <function foo at 0x7fb6ec6349d8> <function foo at 0x7fb6ed41a268>
dill output:  b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x0ct\x00d\x01\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x00S\x00q\x05NX\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x06\x86q\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00printq\x08\x85q\t)X\x10\x00\x00\x00testCloneFunc.pyq\nX\x03\x00\x00\x00fooq\x0bK\x05C\x02\x00\x01q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nX\x0c\x00\x00\x00IAmFooCopiedq\x0fNN}q\x10tq\x11Rq\x12.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCloneFunc.py", line 12, in <module>
    print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (fooCopy) )
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function foo at 0x7fb6ec6349d8>: it's not the same object as __main__.foo
```

The first thing that I found strange, if that If you print the copy, you get the same name as the original, where I expected it to be 'IAmFooCopied'.

Then for the error I guess pickle is also tricked into thinking the two objects are the sames.

Some docs about this pickle error: https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/IssuesWithPickleModule.wiki

But I really don't understand why pickle cannot see that theses two functions are not the sames. Is there any quick fix I can use?

Edit: It seem that the the name argument of the FunctionType do not set co_name of the function, nether it set **qualname**. So by recreating a code object, I fixed the old error just to encounter this one:

```py
import dill
import pickle
import types

def foo():
    print ('a')


oldCode=foo.__code__

name='IAmFooCopied'

newCode= types.CodeType(
        oldCode.co_argcount,             #   integer
        oldCode.co_kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
        oldCode.co_nlocals,              #   integer
        oldCode.co_stacksize,            #   integer
        oldCode.co_flags,                #   integer
        oldCode.co_code,                 #   bytes
        oldCode.co_consts,               #   tuple
        oldCode.co_names,                #   tuple
        oldCode.co_varnames,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_filename,             #   string
        name,                  #   string
        oldCode.co_firstlineno,          #   integer
        oldCode.co_lnotab,               #   bytes
        oldCode.co_freevars,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_cellvars              #   tuple
        )


fooCopy=types.FunctionType(newCode, foo.__globals__, name,foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__)

fooCopy.__qualname__= name

print ( 'printing foo and the copy', fooCopy, foo )
print ( 'dill output: ', dill.dumps(fooCopy ))
print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (fooCopy) )
```

New output:

```
printing foo and the copy <function IAmFooCopied at 0x7fee8ebb19d8> <function foo at 0x7fee8f996268>
dill output:  b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x0ct\x00d\x01\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x00S\x00q\x05NX\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x06\x86q\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00printq\x08\x85q\t)X\x10\x00\x00\x00testCloneFunc.pyq\nX\x0c\x00\x00\x00IAmFooCopiedq\x0bK\x05C\x02\x00\x01q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x0ftq\x10Rq\x11.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCloneFunc.py", line 38, in <module>
    print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (fooCopy) )
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function IAmFooCopied at 0x7fee8ebb19d8>: attribute lookup IAmFooCopied on __main__ failed
```

Also, dill.detect fail to detect any problem.

Comment: Also, please if you put a -1, explain why

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do here... but just to be clear -- `dill` works as expected.

```
>>> import dill                                              
>>> import pickle
>>> import types
>>> 
>>> def foo():
...     print ('a')
... 
>>> fooCopy=types.FunctionType(foo.__code__, foo.__globals__, 'IAmFooCopied',foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__)
>>>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(foo))
<function foo at 0x1058172a8>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(fooCopy))
<function IAmFooCopied at 0x105817320>
>>>
```

`pickle` fails because it generally fails to serialize user-built functions in many cases as it serializes the functions by reference (i.e. reference to the module it was built in).  You can see in the dumped string, `pickle` basically stores a string that amounts to a prefix of which serialization version to use, then the name of the module (`__main__`), then the name of the function ('IAmFooCopied'). `dill`, on the other hand, does exactly what you are doing by hand.  See `save_function` and `_create_function` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_dill.py.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that work:

```py
import pickle
import dill
import types

def foo():
    print ('a')


oldCode=foo.__code__

name='IAmFooCopied'

newCode= types.CodeType(
        oldCode.co_argcount,             #   integer
        oldCode.co_kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
        oldCode.co_nlocals,              #   integer
        oldCode.co_stacksize,            #   integer
        oldCode.co_flags,                #   integer
        oldCode.co_code,                 #   bytes
        oldCode.co_consts,               #   tuple
        oldCode.co_names,                #   tuple
        oldCode.co_varnames,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_filename,             #   string
        name,                  #   string
        oldCode.co_firstlineno,          #   integer
        oldCode.co_lnotab,               #   bytes
        oldCode.co_freevars,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_cellvars              #   tuple
        )

IAmFooCopied=types.FunctionType(newCode, foo.__globals__, name,foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__)
IAmFooCopied.__qualname__= name
print ( 'printing foo and the copy', IAmFooCopied, foo )
print ( 'dill output: ', dill.dumps(IAmFooCopied ))
print ( 'pickle Output: ', pickle.dumps (IAmFooCopied) )
```

If the definition of the function (`IAmFooCopied=types.FunctionType(newCode, foo.__globals__, name,foo.__defaults__ , foo.__closure__`) and the name='IAmFooCopied' do not match, pickle cant find the function to serialize.

Output:

```
printing foo and the copy <function IAmFooCopied at 0x7f8a6a8159d8> <function foo at 0x7f8a6b5f5268>
dill output:  b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x0ct\x00d\x01\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x00S\x00q\x05NX\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x06\x86q\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00printq\x08\x85q\t)X\x10\x00\x00\x00testCloneFunc.pyq\nX\x0c\x00\x00\x00IAmFooCopiedq\x0bK\x05C\x02\x00\x01q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x0ftq\x10Rq\x11.'
pickle Output:  b'\x80\x03c__main__\nIAmFooCopied\nq\x00.'
```