# Excluding modules when importing everything in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import

**Problem**

Consider the following layout:

```
package/
    main.py
    math_helpers/
        mymath.py
        __init__.py
```

`mymath.py` contains:

```
import math

def foo():
    pass
```

In `main.py` I want to be able to use code from `mymath.py` like so:

```
import math_helpers
math_helpers.foo()
```

In order to do so, `__init__.py` contains:

```
from .mymath import *
```

However, modules imported in `mymath.py` are now in the `math_helpers` namespace, e.g. `math_helpers.math` is accessible.

---

**Current approach**

I'm adding the following at the end of `mymath.py`.

```
import types
__all__ = [name for name, thing in globals().items()
          if not (name.startswith('_') or isinstance(thing, types.ModuleType))]
```

This seems to work, but is it the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what it’s for.

Comment: Don't forget to do `del types` after defining `__all__`

Comment: I've posted an answer. Hopefully it adds to what you already figured out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the one hand there are many good reasons not to do star imports, but on the other hand, python is for consenting adults.

`__all__` is the recommended approach to determining what shows up in a star import. Your approach is correct, and you can further sanitize the namespace when finished:

```
import types
__all__ = [name for name, thing in globals().items()
          if not (name.startswith('_') or isinstance(thing, types.ModuleType))]
del types
```

While less recommended, you can also sanitize elements directly out of the module, so that they don't show up at all. This will be a problem if you need to use them in a function defined in the module, since every function object has a `__globals__` reference that is bound to its parent module's `__dict__`. But if you only import `math_helpers` to call `math_helpers.foo()`, and don't require a persistent reference to it elsewhere in the module, you can simply unlink it at the end:

```
del math_helpers
```

**Long Version**

A module import runs the code of the module in the namespace of the module's `__dict__`. Any names that are bound at the top level, whether by class definition, function definition, direct assignment, or other means, live in the that dictionary. Sometimes, it is desirable to clean up intermediate variables, as I suggested doing with `types`.

Let's say your module looks like this:

**test_module.py**

```
import math
import numpy as np

def x(n):
    return math.sqrt(n)

class A(np.ndarray):
    pass

import types
__all__ = [name for name, thing in globals().items()
           if not (name.startswith('_') or isinstance(thing, types.ModuleType))]
```

In this case, `__all__` will be `['x', 'A']`. However, the module itself will contain the following names: `'math', 'np', 'x', 'A', 'types', '__all__'`.

If you run `del types` at the end, it will remove that name from the namespace. Clearly this is safe because `types` is not referenced anywhere once `__all__` has been constructed.

Similarly, if you wanted to remove `np` by adding `del np`, that would be OK. The class `A` is fully constructed by the end of the module code, so it does not require the global name `np` to reference its parent class.

Not so with `math`. If you were to do `del math` at the end of the module code, the function `x` would not work. If you import your module, you can see that `x.__globals__` is the module's `__dict__`:

```
import test_module

test_module.__dict__ is test_module.x.__globals__
```

If you delete `math` from the module dictionary and call `test_module.x`, you will get

```
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

So you under some very special circumstances you may be able to sanitize the namespace of `mymath.py`, but that is not the recommended approach as it only applies to certain cases.

In conclusion, stick to using `__all__`.

**A Story That's Sort of Relevant**

One time, I had two modules that implemented similar functionality, but for different types of end users. There were a couple of functions that I wanted to copy out of module `a` into module `b`. The problem was that I wanted the functions to work as if they had been defined in module `b`. Unfortunately, they depended on a constant that was defined in `a`. `b` defined its own version of the constant. For example:

**a.py**

```
value = 1

def x():
    return value
```

**b.py**

```
from a import x

value = 2
```

I wanted `b.x` to access `b.value` instead of `a.value`. I pulled that off by adding the following to `b.py` (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503277/2988730):

```
import functools, types

x = functools.update_wrapper(types.FunctionType(x.__code__, globals(), x.__name__, x.__defaults__, x.__closure__), x)
x.__kwdefaults__ = x.__wrapped__.__kwdefaults__
x.__module__ = __name__
del functools, types
```

Why am I telling you all this? Well, you can make a version of your module that does not have any stray names in your namespace. You won't be able to see changes to global variables in your functions though. This is just an exercise in pushing python beyond its normal usage. I highly don't recommend doing this, but here is a sample module that effectively freezes its `__dict__` as far as the functions are concerned. This has the same members as `test_module` above, but with no modules in the global namespace:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def x(n):
    return math.sqrt(n)

class A(np.ndarray):
    pass

import functools, types, sys

def wrap(obj):
    """ Written this way to be able to handle classes """
    for name in dir(obj):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            continue
        thing = getattr(obj, name)
        if isinstance(thing, FunctionType) and thing.__module__ == __name__:
            setattr(obj, name,
                    functools.update_wrapper(types.FunctionType(thing.func_code, d, thing.__name__, thing.__defaults__, thing.__closure__), thing)
            getattt(obj, name).__kwdefaults__ = thing.__kwdefaults__
        elif isinstance(thing, type) and thing.__module__ == __name__:
            wrap(thing)

d = globals().copy()
wrap(sys.modules[__name__])
del d, wrap, sys, math, np, functools, types
```

So yeah, please don't ever do this! But if you do, stick it in a utility class somewhere.

Comment: 1. I know that importing `*` is frowned upon when it is done is such a way that you cannot see where a name comes from, but what's the problem with just pulling everything into `math_helpers`? 2. what's `del types` for? 3. I don't understand the part "since every function object has a `__globals__` reference that is bound to its parent module's `__dict__.`" - Thanks!

Comment: I'll update with an illustration when I get to a desktop

Comment: @actual_panda. There is nothing wrong with putting everything in `math_helpers`. The solution you proposed in the question is the definitely the recommended one. Sorry if that wasn't clear in my rambling. I've added more rambling than you ever wanted to know to answer your other questions.