# What is the best way to pass an np.array into a function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function like this (which I cannot change):

```
def myFunc(x, y):
    nx = int(x)
    ny = int(y)
    Freq = 0.4

    e0 = 1 * gen.noise2d(Freq * nx, Freq * ny)
    return e0 + 500
```

Right now, I am trying to use an `np.ndarray` for other parts of my code, and pass in the `x` and `y` values in my loop one at a time:

```
# passing in a particles which is an array like this:
#     [[2,4], [5, 9], [2, 5]]
# this array would have more than 5000 pairs of x, y coordinates

def mapFunc(particles):
    N = len(particles)
    mask = []
    distance = []

    for i in range(N):
        x = particles[i][0]
        y = particles[i][1]
        ground_dist = mapFunc(x, y)
 
        # add in the distances to the ground
        distance.append(ground_dist)

        # add True if the ground is less than 50 feet away
        mask.append(ground_dist < 50)

    return distance, mask
```

Is there a better/faster/more efficient way to get the values from my `np.ndarray`? Can I somehow pass in the whole arrary into `myFunc`? The problem is `int(x)` and `int(y)`, not sure how to work with that in Python in regards to an array.

Edit 1 - There was a mistake in the return of myFunc, it was supposed to be using e0 to add 500

Edit 2 - the gen.noise2d is from https://github.com/lmas/opensimplex to "Generate 2D OpenSimplex noise from X,Y coordinates."

Comment: `mapFunc() == myFunc()`?

Comment: Do you mean `myFunc(*particle[i])`? (Assuming only ever two elements in the array)

Comment: I'm not sure whether [vectorize()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) could help getting rid of the Python loop

Comment: @ThomasWeller. `vectorize` is a python loop.

Comment: If you can't change that function, there is really not much numpy will do for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yes, I just meant one could perhaps reduce the nesting level of the code by 1 level.

Comment: @ThomasWeller. I actually found a solution that will benefit from numpy.

Comment: @sleo. Is `myFunc` in a different module, and can you mess with the function object? I.e., are you allowed to do something like `myFunc.a = 3` in your part of the code?

Comment: Also, what is `gen.noise2D`? Is it something similar that can be potentially vectorized but you aren't allowed to mess with either?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Just tried it out and it seems like I can actually mess with objects in there. That is, it's letting me do something like: `myFunc.nx = int(3)`

Comment: In that case, welcome to the world of monkey-patching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fully vectorize your code if the following two conditions are met:

1. `gen.noise2d` is vectorizable (possibly using the technique shown below), or ignorable
2. `myFunc` is a python function, as opposed to one written in C

You can monkeypatch the name `int` it `myFunc`'s global namespace to refer to [`np.around`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) or [`np.trunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trunc.html). The latter is closer to what `int` currently does in the code:

```
myFunc.__globals__['int'] = np.trunc
```

You may need to either modify the dependencies of `myFunc.__globals__['gen']['noise2d']`, or swap it out entirely. Alternatively, you may want to ignore the `noise2d` function entirely since its result does not appear to be used in the first place.

Now you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
def mapFunc(particles):
    particles = np.asarray(particles)
    distance = myFunc(*particles.T)
    mask = distance < 50
    return distance, mask
```

The line `myFunc.__globals__['int'] = np.trunc` will modify the `__dict__` of the module that `myFunc` is defined in. This may be a bad thing if you want to use the real `int` elsewhere in that module. Since the `__globals__` attribute is read-only, you can create a copy of the function object with the original code and a different globals. This is likely overkill, so I will link you to the following post: [How to create a copy of a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13503079/2988730).

Perhaps a simpler solution is just to bind a different object to the name `myFunc`, and assign it to the appropriate module?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be on the right track. I made an error in my question, it is using the result from noise2d result in the return line, I just corrected it in the question `return e0 + 500`

Comment: @sleo. In that case, I recommend adding that function to the question. If this answer helps you move forward, I suggest selecting it by clicking on the check mark next to it. That will remove your question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: So I dug a bit deeper and now it seems like `gen.noise2d` is causing problems. This is guy is from https://github.com/lmas/opensimplex   Now its saying the line in noise2d `xsb = floor(xs)` is the culprit, giving the error message `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @sleo. That's because `math.floor` calls `__float__` on the input. Numpy arrays support that just fine, but you can't convert a multi-array element to a single float, hence the error. So monkey-patch `floor` to `numpy.floor`: `myFunc.__globals__['gen']['noise2d'].__globals__['floor'] = np.floor`. It's a lot of work for something that should already be vectorized, but I hope you're at least having fun with it.

Comment: @sleo. The semi-nice thing about monkeypatching in numpy functions like that is that you aren't likely to break anything. The scalar interface is essentially the same, and duck typing ensures that if your outputs are an array instead of a float, none of the consumers will care since it behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried it out but no dice: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. Tried digging a bit, and it seems like the OpenSimplex import is not letting me change the globals in there. I am kind of stuck using these functions, which for the life of me I can't figure out why they would make it so constraint to not being able to use numpy.

Comment: @sleo. Please ask another question. I suspect that the issue is not what you think it is, just that you're accessing the wrong object. It may be that `gen` is a class with a static `noise2d` method, which just requires different access. If you ask a question, you can post all the info I would need to answer, which you can't really do in a comment.

Comment: Also, why are you tied to this library? The concept is nice, but the implementation is pretty terrible.

Comment: @sleo And if you do post another question, be sure to ping me here, as well as to show exactly how you get the `gen` object. I did not realize that it is something that you are making in your own namespace. I thought `gen` was a module...