# Python functools partial efficiency

Tags: python, function, partial, functools

I have been working with Python and I set up the following code situation:

```
import timeit

setting = """
import functools

def f(a,b,c):
    pass

g = functools.partial(f,c=3)    
h = functools.partial(f,b=5,c=3)   
i = functools.partial(f,a=4,b=5,c=3)
"""

print timeit.timeit('f(4,5,3)', setup = setting, number=100000)
print timeit.timeit('g(4,5)', setup = setting, number=100000)
print timeit.timeit('h(4)', setup = setting, number=100000)
print timeit.timeit('i()', setup = setting, number=100000)
```

I get the following as a result:

```
f: 0.181384086609
g: 0.39066195488
h: 0.425783157349
i: 0.391901016235
```

Why do the calls to the partial functions take longer? Is the partial function just forwarding the parameters to the original function or is it mapping the static arguments throughout? And also, is there a function in Python to return the body of a function filled in given that all the parameters are predefined, like with function i?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Why do the calls to the partial functions take longer?

The code with `partial` takes about two times longer because of the additional function call. Function calls [are expensive:](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

> Function call overhead in Python is relatively high, especially compared with the execution speed of a builtin function.

-

> Is the partial function just forwarding the parameters to the original function or is it mapping the static arguments throughout?

As far as i know - yes, it just [forwards the arguments to the original function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

-

> And also, is there a function in Python to return the body of a function filled in given that all the parameters are predefined, like with function i?

No, i am not aware of such built-in function in Python. But i think it's possible to do what you want, as functions are objects which can be copied and modified.

Here is a prototype:

```
import timeit
import types


# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527633/how-can-i-make-a-deepcopy-of-a-function-in-python
def copy_func(f, name=None):
    return types.FunctionType(f.func_code, f.func_globals, name or f.func_name,
        f.func_defaults, f.func_closure)


def f(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c


i = copy_func(f, 'i')
i.func_defaults = (4, 5, 3)


print timeit.timeit('f(4,5,3)', setup = 'from __main__ import f', number=100000)
print timeit.timeit('i()', setup = 'from __main__ import i', number=100000)
```

which gives:

```
0.0257439613342
0.0221881866455
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any chance you or anyone would be able to give me a tip on how to do that? Would it involve manipulating the byte-code object (function.__code__) or can it be done just through the function object?

Comment: i've updated my answer. but are you really concerned about the speed? what's your problem?

Comment: You are absolutely amazing. Thankyou. And for interests sake, I am working on a Python API and wanted a way for a developer to define a function on one element, then insert that function into a fast loop, but the function calls in the Python implementation I am working with are quite prohibitive to speed (as can be seen from my timeit results.

Answer (score 11):

Calls to a function with partially applied arguments are more expensive because you double the number of function calls. The effect of `functools.partial()` is similar to this example:

```
def apply_one_of_two(f, a):
    def g(b):
        return f(a, b)
    return g
```

That means that `apply_one_of_two()` returns a function and when it's called than this results in the additional call of the original funciton `f`.

Since Python usually doesn't optimize this away it directly translates into additional runtime efforts.

But this isn't the only factor to consider in your microbenchmark. You also switch from positional to keyword arguments in your partial invocations, which introduces additional overhead.

When you reverse the argument ordering in your original function you don't need keyword arguments in the partial calls and then the runtime difference somewhat decreases, e.g.:

```
import timeit

setting = """
import functools

def f(a,b,c):
    pass

g = functools.partial(f, 4)
h = functools.partial(f, 4, 5)
i = functools.partial(f, 4, 5, 3)
"""

print(timeit.timeit('f(4, 5, 3)', setup = setting, number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit('g(5, 3)',    setup = setting, number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit('h(3)',       setup = setting, number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit('i()',        setup = setting, number=100000))
```

Output (on an Intel Skylake i7 under Fedora 27/Python 3.6):

```
0.010069019044749439
0.01681053702486679
0.018060395028442144
0.011366961000021547
```