# Python extracting body from function at runtime

Tags: python, function

Given a function in Python defined as follows:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 5
def add():
    d = a+b+c
```

is it possible to get a code object or similar that gives me:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 5
d = a+b+c
```

Comment: Maybe, but why? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @LennartRegebro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388438/python-functools-partial-efficiency/17388981#comment25245627_17388981

Comment: OK, so you want to get rid of the function call. I would think there is a better way (but admittedly, I'm not sure).

Comment: I second @lennart on this - the answer is yes - what problem are you actually trying to solve though?

Comment: With the real problem, I am developing an API where a developer can define a function on each pixel in an image sequence, and I can then pass the function body to a wrapper function which runs the body in an optimised loop. If I can't manage it any other way, it is always possible to just have developers write the inner code in a string I can execute, but it seems ugly. Any alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function object has a code object associated with it; you can `exec` that code object:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> c = 5
>>> def add():
...     d = a+b+c
... 
>>> exec add.func_code
```

This will *not* however set `d` in the local namespace, because it is compiled to create a *local* name only, using the `STORE_FAST` opcode. You'd have to *transform* this bytecode to use `STORE_DEREF` opcodes instead, requiring you to learn AST transformations.

If you *did* want to go down this route, then read [Exploring Dynamic Scoping in Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/code_blocks.shtml), which teaches you the ins and outs of Python scoping and byte code.

Comment: I like this approach to the problem; I don't necessarily need to worry about compiling time of byte-code, just the end performance. However, I am working on an implementation of Python 2.7 which is restricted to the standard modules only, so Byteplay is unavailable. Is it possible to iterate over bytecode from straight Python?

Comment: Never mind; just saw [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498242/). This would work well. Thanks.

Comment: @user2515310: There is, using the `ast` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` command, which 
is the most simple way in my opinion

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> c = 5
>>> def add():
        global d
...     d = a+b+c
```

Comment: `d` variable inside function `add` will still be local

Comment: @Drarqua The first line is not needed.