# Is there a cost to using functools.partial()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The higher-order function `functools.partial()` can create a new function as follows:

```
newf(arg1) = functools.partial( f, arg1, val )
```

which is obviously equivalent to just saying

```
def newf(arg1): return f( arg1, val )
```

in terms of what they do. But what about performance?  Does `functools.partial()` actually create a new function that does not need to call `f` or are they identical?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals a number of similar or duplicate questions. This is the [top result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388438/python-functools-partial-efficiency). It might help if you used a more specific title, too; you're specifically concerned with performance, not just something 'about' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> import functools
> def nop():
...:     pass
...: 

> %timeit nop()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 63.5 ns per loop

> %timeit functools.partial(nop)()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 205 ns per loop
```

So I would say it looks pretty trivial unless you are doing something silly. And we can get most of that back if we're going to be calling the partial multiple times:

```
> f = functools.partial(nop)
> %timeit f()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 86.7 ns per loop
```

Comment: I agree with this answer.. I can not think of a reason that `partial` would be expensive. So go for it ;)

Comment: I guess what I'm really trying to ask is if the two functions are completely identical, or if there is some difference in the way they are executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the source code of `functools.partial` in python 3.4:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    """New function with partial application of the given arguments
    and keywords.
    """
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc

try:
    from _functools import partial
except ImportError:
    pass
```

on the top it defines a purely python fall-back version, and on the bottom it tries to import the C version. You can find the C code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6829f7aa6705d612448226e17df6d9ce4176f8fc/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L26).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current implementation of `partial`.

Do you understand it? Else ask, but i found it very hard to explain cleanly
because of all the inner and outer functions.

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    """New function with partial application of the given arguments
    and keywords.
    """
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```