# Does python's partial inline calls?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inline, functools

So would this `par`:

```
path = u'/a/b/c'
lam = lambda f: f.lower().startswith(u'distantlod')
par = functools.partial(lam, path)
```

and this `par`:

```
path = u'/a/b/c'
startsWith = path.lower().startswith
par = lambda: startsWith(u'distantlod')
```

be equivalent ? If not why ?

Comment: Perhaps related: [What functionality does functools.partial offer that you can't get through lambdas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary)

Comment: @yuvi: It is related but does not answer this particular question - also related is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17388438/281545

Comment: Could you clarify how you define 'equivalent'?

Comment: @jamesc: in terms of performance (what inline is about). `par` is a function in both cases doing the same thing when called as par() - but in the second case `path.lower().startswith` is inlined in the call (saving us two dots). It seems python could do this in the first case - does it do it and if not why (or what am I missing) ?

Comment: If you want to compare performance you can always [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Comment: @yuvi: would timeit answer why also ? ;) It's more of a language design question really (and a stylistic one maybe)

Comment: If you're asking about usage difference as per styling and readability then I think the link I left answers that. If it's performance I believe the difference is negligible, but you can use timeit and test it out. What else are you asking for?

Comment: I just tested it. While the second version is almost twice as fast, we're talking about a 200-250 nano-seconds difference, so yeah, pretty negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my experiment with cProfile to see if I can confirm @yuvi's measurements above.

**CODE**: `par_profile.py`

```
import cProfile as profile
import functools


path = u'/a/b/c'

lam = lambda f: f.lower().startswith(u'distantlod')
par = functools.partial(lam, path)

startsWith = path.lower().startswith
par2 = lambda: startsWith(u'distantlod')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile.run("for _ in range(1000000): par()")
    profile.run("for _ in range(1000000): par2()")
```

**OUT**

```
$ python par_profile.py 
         3000003 function calls in 0.536 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.148    0.148    0.536    0.536 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.242    0.000    0.388    0.000 par_profile.py:7(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.536    0.536 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    0.054    0.000    0.054    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
  1000000    0.092    0.000    0.092    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}


         2000003 function calls in 0.347 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.130    0.130    0.347    0.347 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.126    0.000    0.218    0.000 par_profile.py:11(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.347    0.347 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    0.092    0.000    0.092    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
```

Firstly it looks like these measurements on my machine tally with @yuvi's numbers:

- `par` is about 540 nanoseconds
- `par2` is about 350 nanoseconds

So I agree `par2` looks faster by about 200 ns.

It looks like if you're trying to compare `lambda` and `partial` it's not a fair test - `par2` has one less call since it doesn't call `lower`, whereas `par` does.

To illustrate why, `startsWith` could be rewritten as:

```
lower_path = path.lower()
startsWith = lower_path.startswith
```

... so `par2` is just a `lambda` that contains a single `startswith` whereas `par` is a partial that contains both `lower` and `startswith` calls.

Therefore they are not equivalent and `par` is slower as a result.

**WHY?**

The question is "why `f.lower().startswith` is not inlined - what prohibits the language from inlining it?"

Firstly, this Python itself does not prohibit this kind of inlining - it's the different Python implementations that makes the decisions, in the case of my tests above it's cpython 3.

Secondly, `partial`'s job is not to inline functions, it just...

> “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial))

Instead if you're looking at something that will do inlining in Python, then I'd check out something like [Numba's jit](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html) or run some experiments with PyPy (please post back here if you find some interesting improvements).

If you're not able to find anything that'll do the inlining you're looking for, then maybe it's a good case for a new Python module!

Comment: Thanks - what I am asking however is _why_ `f.lower().startswith` is not inlined - what prohibits the language from inlining it ?

Comment: Updated to include my answer on why. Hope you find it helpful.