# Is there any way you can get back to the original function?

Tags: python, function

Let's say I want to replace some action of a class temporarily by applying some formula to `something.action` like this,

```
something.action = apply(something.action)
```

Later, I want to apply back the original action method to the instance `something` by doing something like this

```
something.action = ...
```

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the problem at hand cannot be solved using inheritance/wrapping rather than patching (messing with) objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can simply save the original function and write

```
tmp = something.action
something.action = apply(something.action)
```

and then, later

```
something.action = tmp
```

Example:

```
class mytest:
    def action(self):
        print 'Original'

a = mytest()
a.action()

tmp = a.action

def apply(f):
    print 'Not the ',
    return f

a.action = apply(a.action)
a.action()

a.action = tmp
a.action()
```

which gives

```
$ python test.py
Original
Not the  Original
Original
```

Comment: I tried that, but I think by doing `something.action = apply(something.action)`, since tmp is bounded to something.action, tmp would change as well to the new applied action.

Comment: @Chan no it won't as long as "apply" does what it should do - creates copy of the something.action and returns it. If it changes action "in place", than it is wrongly used as a function instead of in place procedure, and then the whole information is lost so you need to copy the function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527633/how-can-i-make-a-deepcopy-of-a-function-in-python

Comment: @lejlot Oh.. So how do you copy a function?

Comment: Functions are first-class objects in Python, like integers or strings. They are copied on assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is to store the action in the same object, but with a different name:

```
something._old_action = something.action
something.action = apply(something._old_action) # this way you can still use it
something.action = lambda x: print(x)           # or you can ignore it completely
do_some_stuff()
something.action = something._old_action
```

Note that we're storing the old action in the object and we can use it. By starting the name with _, we inform that this attribute is private (purely a convention, but it's all we have in Python)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this rather than messing with your object?

```
class Original(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42

    def hello(self):
        print self.x

class OriginalWrapper(Original):
    def __init__(self, original):
        self.__class__ = type(original.__class__.__name__,
                              (self.__class__, original.__class__), {})
        self.__dict__ = original.__dict__

    def hello(self):
        print self.x + 10

original = Original()
original.hello() #42
wrapped = OriginalWrapper(original)
wrapped.hello() #52
```