# How to get builtin_function_or_method objects copied in ram without wrapping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, cpython

Sounds quite simple, but I couldn’t found a solution anywhere. I need to copy a built‑in function object *(I’m not talking about the function code but the object that represent it)* such as :

```
id(func)≠id(func_copy)
```

Where func and func_copy share the same object type.
However if *(for example)* I do :

```
import copy
new_type=copy.copy(oct)
```

then `id(new_type)` and `id(oct)` are still equal.

I also couldn’t found how to modify `oct` attributes or append attribute to it *(it would have resulted in changing the idea)*.

## Update

**This question isn’t a duplicate because copy python function and built‑in function isn’t the same problem : you can’t copy built‑in function objects with the same methods for python function objects and vice versa**.

So none of the solutions on [How can I make a deepcopy of a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6527633/2284570a) can work here.

**Please vote to re‑open**

Comment: copy.deepcopy might work?

Comment: @reptilicus : nope I tried it and it doesn’t.

Comment: Why? The simplest solution may to just make a new function `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` that calls the original function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527633/how-can-i-make-a-deepcopy-of-a-function-in-python

Comment: but yes, "why" is a good question...

Comment: @JaredGoguen : Well internally, `PyObject` representing built‑in functions are loaded into read‑only memory after python initialized. I want a `PyObject` of type `PyCFunctionObject` stored into a place of ʀᴀᴍ with write permissions *(I’m still talking about the .rdata variable, not the .text segment containing the code)*.

Comment: @reptilicus : The solutions don’t work for built‑in functions.

Comment: What about: `func_copy = lambda: func` or `func_copy = lambda x: func(x)`? I don't really understand your use case, but this was just something that popped into my head.

Comment: @elethan : then `func_copy` is wrapper of `func`, not a copy of the `func` object. `func_copy` is python function, not a built‑in function.

Comment: Are you trying to write some sort of exploit again? You really need to make it clearer from the start that you're trying to defeat Python's protections, or you'll just get people telling you that Python doesn't let you do that.

Comment: @user2357112 : If python doesn’t let me do that, I have still the golden hammer way to it. But normally I think python let you to copy all kind of objects or class.

Comment: "But normally I think python let you to copy all kind of objects." - nope! That's completely wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 : do you mean the `__dict__` attribute is a requirement ? But as I said, the gold hammer way would be to read  and parse memory for changing C structures *(would require several tens line of code)*.

Comment: Whether an object has a `__dict__` has nothing to do with whether Python will let you copy it.

Comment: If you're talking about the underlying C representation of things then by very definition _you're not talking about Python!_ You're talking about implementation details, which makes this question similar to "Why is `x = 3; y = 3; x is y == True` in Python?" Because it's only applicable to CPython. If you want to know how copy works _read the source_.

Comment: @WayneWerner : Actually, in cpython, a C *PyObject and a python object are the same thing. And yes, my question is CPython specific, hence the tag.