# Dynamic class definition with methods from multiple modules

Tags: python, class, methods, copy

I try to create classes with quite extensive methods defined in multiple modules. I need some wrappers to ensure compatibility with other classes and cannot change my modules greatly. Here is an attempt of a minimal example:

---

Let my (many) modules be something like:

```
"""moduleA.py"""
def print_something(text):
    print(f"Here is some output from module A: {text}")
```

and just a second for the example:

```
"""moduleB.py"""
def print_something(text):
    print(f"Here is some output from module B: {text}")
```

---

If I build a dynamic class definition around many of such modules, the assignment of my method does not work as hoped:

```
import os
import re
from importlib import import_module

# create class for every pyd-module in current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
for fileName in os.listdir(cwd):
    if re.search('module.+\.py', fileName):
        moduleName = re.split('\.', fileName)[0]
        module = import_module(moduleName)

        # wrapper does something needed
        def print_wrapper(self, text):
            module.print_something(text.upper())

        className = 'ClassM'+moduleName[1:]
        dynamicClass = type(className, (object, ), {
            "print_something": print_wrapper})
        # register dynamic class for use
        globals()[dynamicClass.__name__] = dynamicClass

instanceA = ClassModuleA()
instanceA.print_something("testA")
instanceB = ClassModuleB()
instanceB.print_something("testB")
```

output (only from module B and not from module A):

> ```
> Here is some output from module B: TESTA
> Here is some output from module B: TESTB
> ```

---

I tried to use copy operations, but they do not work for builtin_function_or_method(s). (see:
[How to get builtin_function_or_method objects copied in ram without wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353158)
and
[How can I make a deepcopy of a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527633))

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with Cython. In these kind of cases it's worth testing with plain Python as well (i.e. "minimizing" your minimum reproducible example).

```
def print_wrapper(self, text):  # wrapper does something needed
    module.print_something(text.upper())
```

This says "look up the current value of `module` in the global scope and call its attribute `print_something`". The current value of `module` is evaluated at *the point the function is called* and thus is always the last one in the loop.

There's a number of techniques to capture variables at definition time, but one option might be

```
def print_wrapper(self, text, local_module=module):  # wrapper does something needed
    local_module.print_something(text.upper())
```

---

In the line `if re.search('.pyd', fileName):`, you're aware that `.` has a special meaning in regexes, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense and works fine. I was unnecessarily at a loss there.
I reduced my example by cython to avoid confusion of others and corrected the unrelated regex mistake.