# How do I write a decorator to retrieve cached files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pipeline that contains several variations of the following data class, which I've tried to maximally simplify for this example:

```
from pathlib import Path

class Data(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.filepath = Path("filepath")  

    def download(self, use_cache=True):
        if use_cache and self.filepath.exists():
            return self.filepath
        # Code to download 
        print(f"downloading to {self.filepath}")
```

I'd like to perform the download only if (a) the file doesn't exist, and (b) the user provides the arg `use_cache = False`. As mentioned, I have several classes with similar `download` methods that only vary in the `# Code to download` portion. I'd like to find a way to make the caching logic generic for all of these.

I was thinking about using a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def cache(filepath, use_cache):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if filepath.exists() and use_cache:
                return filepath 
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

However, I'm not sure how to pass the `filepath` and `use_cache` arguments to the cache decorator. Am I going about this completely wrong? How else could I solve this problem?

Comment: The wrapper should consume the `use_cache` argument, and if I understand correctly, it won't need to call `download` in that case. I'd post an answer but your code is a mess. I really don't understand why you're using a class with a blank `__init__()` and methods that don't really use `self`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a [mre]. Like, instead of downloading a file, you could try something simpler like inserting keys in a dict.

Comment: @wjandrea can you clarify what you mean by "The wrapper should consume the use_cache argument, and if I understand correctly, it won't need to call download in that case. "? I've fixed the typos and tried to clarify the question. I'm trying to keep the class as simple as possible for this example, in reality it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Excellent clarification! OK, I think you already knew "it won't need to call `download`", and I was confused about the `use_cache` argument because of the way you wrote it before but now I see what you're trying to do. I'll write an answer, but two things to clarify still: 1) `Path` is unused; maybe you mean `self.filepath = Path("filepath")`? 2) The title is vague; I'm thinking it'd be clearer to put something like "How do I write a decorator to retrieve cached files?" Keep in mind a good title will attract better answers :)

Comment: (1) Yes sorry that was a typo (2) Good point, I've updated the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrapper()` needs to intercept the arguments `self` and `use_cache`. Then, if I understand correctly, it doesn't need to pass on `use_cache` to `download()`.

As well, your decorator seems to be one level too deep. Really you've written a decorator *factory*, which doesn't seem necessary here.

```
from functools import wraps
from pathlib import Path

def filecache(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, use_cache=True, **kwargs):
        if self.filepath.exists() and use_cache:
            return self.filepath
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Also added return here
    return wrapper

class Data:
    def __init__(self, filepath):  # Using "filepath" parameter for this example
        self.filepath = Path(filepath)

    @filecache
    def download(self, use_cache=True):
        print(f"downloading to {str(self.filepath)!r}")
        return self.filepath  # Also added return here to mirror wrapper
```

Usage:

```
>>> root = Data('/')
>>> root.filepath.exists()
True
>>> root.download()  # Uses cache
PosixPath('/')
>>> root.download(use_cache=False)  # Doesn't use cache
downloading to '/'
PosixPath('/')
```

```
>>> dne = Data('/DNE')
>>> dne.filepath.exists()
False
>>> dne.download()  # Doesn't use cache
downloading to '/DNE'
PosixPath('/DNE')
```

In theory, you can then remove the parameter `use_cache=True` from `download()`, but then it's missing from `help(download)` and I don't know how to add it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67034463/4518341) has a solution, but it relies on implementation details. One way to see the actual arguments is [`inspect.signature(follow_wrapped=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```
>>> inspect.signature(Data.download, follow_wrapped=False)
<Signature (self, *args, use_cache=True, **kwargs)>
```