# Python copy a class such that unbound methods no longer same underlying object

Tags: python, class, methods, copy

I have a class like so:

```py
class Foo:
    def spam(self) -> None:
        pass
```

I want to copy the class to new name `CopyFoo`, **and notably** have the copy's underlying methods be totally different objects.

How can I copy `Foo`, and have the unbound method `spam` be a different unbound method?

Note: I need to do this without instantiating `Foo`, having bound methods be different objects doesn't help me.

**Research**

From [How to copy a python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class), I have tried `copy.deepcopy`, pairing `pickle.loads` + `pickle.dumps`, and using `type`, to no avail.

```
>>> Foo.spam
<function Foo.spam at 0x111a6a0d0>
>>> deepcopy(Foo).spam
<function Foo.spam at 0x111a6a0d0>
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Foo)).spam
<function Foo.spam at 0x111a6a0d0>
>>> type('CopyFoo', Foo.__bases__, dict(Foo.__dict__)).spam
<function Foo.spam at 0x111a6a0d0>
```

Comment: The problem is that you're copying the class itself as opposed to an instance of the class. If you create a Foo object and you call copy.deepcopy(obj), it will properly create a deepcopy.

Comment: That said, I did find a previous answer to your question, as it is an interesting one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class

Comment: Thank you @MatthewKligerman, yes I had already tried the solutions in that question. I updated my question to add more details, so far no solution yet

Comment: You probably have to iterate through the class attributes, detect methods and create copies of them. As they are ordinary functions you can use the answer of Aaron Hall on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527633/how-can-i-make-a-deepcopy-of-a-function-in-python

Comment: why not inherit Foo.`class CopyFoo(Foo):`

Comment: @nay Then `spam` method will be inherited too.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why would it ever matter?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a hack and should not be used in production but posting it anyway for future reference:

```
import inspect

class Foo:
    def spam(self) -> None:
        pass


foo_source = inspect.getsource(Foo)
copy_foo_source = foo_source.replace("Foo", "CopyFoo")

exec(copy_foo_source)

print(f"{id(Foo)=}")
print(f"{id(CopyFoo)=}")
print(f"{id(Foo.spam)=}")
print(f"{id(CopyFoo.spam)=}")
```

the output will be similar to this:

```
id(Foo)=140343301414016
id(CopyFoo)=140343299415168
id(Foo.spam)=4420954432
id(CopyFoo.spam)=4421268528
```